# Switching order of sum and integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I am struggling to understand when an integral and an infinite sum can be switched around. I want to know if they can be switched in the following case:

$$\sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (t x)}{x^{2}+a^{2}}\mathop{dx}$$

I don’t need the reader to evaluate the sum/integral.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904373/when-can-an-infinite-sum-and-complex-integral-be-interchanged) help? Also look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/when-can-a-sum-and-integral-be-interchanged/83747).[Furthermore](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167589/could-someone-remind-me-why-is-incorrect-to-switch-an-infinite-sum-and-an-integr).

Comment: Are you sure the lower index started at $a=0$? The improper integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(tx)\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}$ diverges.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out! I shall edit it now @MatthewH.

Comment: If $t=0$, you get a divergent sum. If $t\neq 0$, then using a change of variables and integration by parts $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\cos (tx)}}{{x^2  + a^2 }}dx}  = \frac{1}{a}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\cos (taz)}}{{z^2  + 1}}dz}  = \frac{1}{{a^2 }}\frac{2}{t}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{z\sin (taz)}}{{(z^2  + 1)^2 }}dz} .
$$ Now $$\left| {\frac{1}{{a^2 }}\frac{2}{t}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{z\sin (taz)}}{{(z^2  + 1)^2 }}dz} } \right| \le \frac{1}{{a^2 }}\frac{2}{{\left| t \right|}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{z}{{(z^2  + 1)^2 }}dz = } \frac{1}{{\left| t \right|}}\frac{1}{{a^2 }}.
$$